# How do I get a "Perfect" in Bit.Trip Runner?

Tags: bit-trip-runner

I've been playing Bit.Trip Runner, trying to ace the Retro Warp Zones and get the "!!" on each level for collecting the gold. *All* the gold.

I had thought that simply collecting all of the gold was sufficient to earn a "perfect", but I managed to get a "!!" score on level 1-5, and yet, I did not also get the "PERFECT!" That I got when "!!"-ing 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, and 1-9.

**Edit:**

As Mr. McClelland points out below, a PERFECT! rating is scored by obtaining the maximum amount of points in the level.

What actions increase your score? I know collecting gold is obviously part of it, but not all obstacles (such as sliding under low overhangs, or jumping gaps) reward points...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very easy way to guarantee you get a perfect score -- simply play on "PERFECT" difficulty. You automatically fail the level if you ever miss something that would contribute to a perfect score. Thus the levels become, simply

> ! = main level completed perfectly
>
> !! = main level & retro warp level completed perfectly (So PERFECT score!!)

If you don't want to restart your save file and play through every level again, however, here's a general guide:

The trick to getting Perfect scores is simply a matter of getting all the gold, and performing all score increasing actions in a single run. In perhaps 90% of the cases, getting all of the gold will get you the perfect score, and there are only a few outliers where you have to make an effort beyond that of simply collecting the gold.

Here are the actions that score points:

- Kicking through a breakable object (Crystals, Stop signs, Boxes)
- Hitting a Springboard
- Bouncing off a Spring enemy.
- Reflecting a Bullet
- Picking up Gold
- Picking up a "+" object.

When given a diverging path with a choice (i.e., either hit a springboard or pick up a gold piece) always follow the gold and the "+" multiplyer, as these two objects are the biggest score boosts by an extremely wide margin.

When given a choice to either hit a points item or survive, chose the latter. Some points objects merely exist to present false choices - going after any item that will result in your immediate subsequent death is *not* required to score the perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit.Trip#Bit.Trip_Runner):

> The perfect completion of a retro challenge will award players with
>   an exclamation point beside the stage and the word "PERFECT" beside
>   the score in the scoreboard, but only if they have done everything
>   "extra" (i.e., jumping on top of springboards that they do not need to
>   in order to finish) in the level beforehand.

**Edit**

According to [this gamefaqs forum thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/984778-bittrip-runner/54896065):

> ! = All golds collected; advanced to Retro
>   level
>
> !! = All golds collected in Retro
>   level

As such, it sounds like you need to not only get all the golds in a zone, but also all the golds in its retro levels.  A bit of forewarning, I don't actually own B.TR, so I can't confirm any of this data.

Comment: Can you find out what all actions you get points for, then, Winter? I know simply jumping over rocks doesn't give you anything.

Comment: @Raven check my update, I found something that may provide some more insight

Comment: Well, your gamefaqs info is wrong. There is no "P" rating, only "!" and "!!". I think that was just that one person's personal tracking, not what was actually showing up in-game.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - I think you need the maximum possible score for the level, i.e. if there are two paths to take at any given point, you have to take whichever yields more points. That basically means whichever is trickier/and or has the gold. You definitely need to hit any springboards you cross. I can't remember if I saw the PERFECT or not now... :(

Comment: [AmbisagrusSA](http://www.youtube.com/user/AmbisagrusSA), [after getting a perfect score in 1-1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2ef6coOFBY), gets [a flashing PERFECT at the score screen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2ef6coOFBY&feature=player_detailpage#t=157s) and [a double exclamation point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRUsSgo3ZfU) on the level selection screen.

Comment: @Raven I believe the gamefaqs thread meant that a P rating was the flashing "Perfect!" at the end of the level that you haven't gotten on some levels that you have completed with a "!!" rating.